# SQL: Count unique user for each specific time

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have two tables (I will call `Table A` and `Table B`)

- `Table A` shows customers daily summary: For my example, a customer visited the store!
- `Table B` shows each item that customer bought: Each item details!

Table A:

```
|Day         |Customer|
| -------   | ------- |
| 2020-01-01 | A |
| 2020-01-01 | B |
| 2020-01-02 | A |
| 2020-01-03 | A |
| 2020-01-03 | B |
| 2020-01-04 | A |
| 2020-01-04 | C |
| 2020-01-05 | D |
| 2020-01-05 | A |
| 2020-01-05 | B |
| 2020-01-06 | C |
| 2020-01-06 | D |
```

Table B:

```
|Day         | Customer| product  | campaign       |
| -------    | -------| -------   | -------        |
| 2020-01-01 |  A     |    11     | Campaign2020101|
| 2020-01-01 |  A     |    1      | NULL           |
| 2020-01-01 |  B     |    13     | Campaign2020101|
| 2020-01-02 |  A     |    15     | Campaign2020101|
| 2020-01-03 |  A     |    16     | Campaign2020101|
| 2020-01-04 |  A     |    17     | Campaign2020104|
| 2020-01-04 |  C     |    1      | NULL           |
| 2020-01-05 |  A     |    17     | Campaign2020104|
| 2020-01-05 |  B     |    1      | NULL           |
| 2020-01-05 |  D     |    1      | NULL           |
| 2020-01-06 |  C     |    19     | Campaign2020106|
| 2020-01-06 |  C     |    19     | Campaign2020106|
| 2020-01-06 |  D     |    19     | Campaign2020106|
```

The problem is finding the number of unique campaign customer compare with each unique customer that visit the store!
So I can find each campaign unique user because I have a unique campaign ID (`GROUP BY`) but the problem is I couldn't separate `Table A` Dates based on campaign dates!

An example:

- Campaign202001:

  - Starts 01/01/2020 end ends 03/01/2020
  - Unique store visit 2 (customer A and customer B)
  - Unique campaign user 2 (Customer A and Customer B)
  - Conversion is 100%
- Campaign2020104:

  - Starts 04/01/2020 end ends 05/01/2020
  - Unique store visit 4 (customer A,B,C and D)
  - Unique campaign user 1 (only Customer A)
  - Conversion is 25%

How can I find unique customer visits for each campaign times?

Sorry: I could not make a unique title!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes I did! What about you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit complicated.  You really need a separate `campaigns` table that has the actual dates of the campaigns.  What if there are no purchases on a particular date?

```
select c.campaign, c.num_campaign_customers,
       count(distinct v.customer) as total_customers,
       num_campaign_customers * 1.0 / count(distinct v.customer) as conversion_rate
from (select campaign, min(day) as min_day, max(day) as max_day,
             count(distinct customer) as num_campaign_customers
      from purchases p
      group by campaign
     ) c join
     visits v
     on v.day >= c.min_day and
        v.day <= c.max_day
group by c.campaign, c.num_campaign_customers;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following query. It is not really optimized, but you can use it as a starting point and then rework it based upon your actual data:

```
with cp (sdate, edate) as
(select min(day) sdate,max(day) edate from b where campaign = 'Campaign2020104')
select count(distinct b.customer) visit,count(distinct purchase.customer) customer
from b, b as purchase,cp where b.day between cp.sdate and cp.edate
and purchase.day between cp.sdate and cp.edate and purchase.campaign is not null;
```

You can test it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3303b/3

Comment: What about if you unlimited campaign?

Comment: If you have a running campaign, the max(day) will change each time a user make a new purchase. If you have the start/end date in some other table, you can use the values from there.

Comment: I mean you are using multiple campaign ID hardcoding. I am asking if you have 1000 campaign will you write down for each one?